# ¿Se pueden tener filtros variables en los WHERE de un procedimientos almacenados en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando migrar una aplicación que utiliza MySQL como base de datos pero que no tenia procedimientos almacenados, en uno de los cuales debo enviar un ordenamiento X dependiendo de las necesidades del usuario, cuando intento hacer que ese ordenamiento sea variable (es decir, envío el valor de como deseo ordenar la consulta) me da el siguiente error:

> Procedure execution failed
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NULL' at line 1

¿Qué me esta haciendo falta en el procedimiento?, acá el código de ejemplo, es solo un ejemplo pues el procedimiento es mas largo.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NO_Example`(IN `tcCodCli`  varchar(15), IN `tcOrden`  varchar(100) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE SELECCION VARCHAR(5000);
    DECLARE ORDEN VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE CONSULTA VARCHAR(10000);

    SET SELECCION = "SELECT *
        FROM cn_terceros
        WHERE codter = tcCodCli ";

    SET ORDEN = tcOrden; 
    SET CONSULTA = CONCAT(SELECCION,ORDEN);

    PREPARE CONSULTA FROM @CONSULTA;
    EXECUTE CONSULTA ;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También tienes que concatenar la variable `tcCodCli` en la cadena de selección:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NO_Example`(IN `tcCodCli`  varchar(15), IN `tcOrden`  varchar(100) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE SELECCION VARCHAR(5000);
    DECLARE ORDEN VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE CONSULTA VARCHAR(10000);

    SET SELECCION = CONCAT('SELECT *
        FROM cn_terceros
        WHERE codter = ' , tcCodCli );

    SET ORDEN = tcOrden; 
    SET CONSULTA = CONCAT(SELECCION, ORDEN) ;

    PREPARE CONSULTA FROM @CONSULTA;
    EXECUTE CONSULTA ;


  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo la respuesta a tu pregunta es SI, si puedes utilizar variables en la clausula `WHERE` dentro de un SP, por otro lado definitavemente el procedimiento asi como lo tienes te puede estar fallando por la falta de delimitadores, fíjate que el procedimiento tiene varias declaraciones que terminan en `;` por lo tanto para compilar el procedimiento como una sola declaracion compuesta tienes que poner todo dentro de delimitadores, algo como esto:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NO_Example`(IN `tcCodCli`     varchar(15), IN `tcOrden`  varchar(100) )
    BEGIN
DECLARE SELECCION VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE ORDEN VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE CONSULTA VARCHAR(10000);

SET SELECCION = "SELECT *
    FROM cn_terceros
    WHERE codter = tcCodCli ";

SET ORDEN = tcOrden; 
SET CONSULTA = CONCAT(SELECCION,ORDEN);

PREPARE CONSULTA FROM @CONSULTA;
EXECUTE CONSULTA ;
END//

DELIMITER;
```